Descriptions of G-d's attributes as white and red in connections with signs of tumah
In a number of places we have descriptions of G-d as "white" and "red". For example, Shir ha Shirim 5:10: My beloved is clear-skinned (white) and ruddy, preeminent among ten thousand. Netsiv in "Rinah shel Torah" (among other commentators) explains that white color refers to the attribute of mercy and the red color refers to the attribute of justice.
When studying Mishnah Negaim 1:1-2 we learn that the signs of tzaraas can be shades of white or shades of red. Additionally, when studying Mishnah Zavim or Mishna Niddah, we find that the signs of tumah for a man are white, while the signs of tumah for a woman are red.
What can be learned from the color similarity?

Very deep: http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/gikatalia/saare_cedek.htm

@RabbiKaii Thank you. Certainly need to toil.
